# Display empty int value in textfield

Tags: int, swiftui, textfield

This is the first screen of my multiplication practice app

[image: This is the first screen of my multiplication practice app]

This is the second screen. The problem is that it shows the previous number which you have to delete to put in a new one. So when I try checking the answer to see if it is right the computer picks up the value that it was given first (a.k.a number "6" in this case)

[image: This is the second screen. The problem is that it shows the previous number which you have to delete to put in a new one. So when I try checking the answer to see if it is right the computer picks up the value that it was given first (a.k.a number "6" in this case)]

this is what my code looks like.

```
struct MultiplicationScreen: View {
@State var answer: Int! = nil
@State var num1 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)
@State var num2 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)
@State var number1:String = "Click Next"
@State var number2:String = "To Start"
@State var correctAnswer: Int = -1

let line = "______"

var multiplicationBrain = MultiplicationBrain()

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        VStack {
            
            Text(self.number1)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.bottom)
            Text(self.number2)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.bottom)
            Text(self.line)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding(.bottom)
                .frame(height: 0.0)
            
            TextField("", value: $answer, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.all)
                .frame(width: 100.0, height: 55.0)
                .border(Color.black)
            
        }
        .padding(.all)
        Button(action: {self.updateUI()}) {
            Text("Next")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.all)
                .frame(width: 250.0, height: 60.0)
                .background(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                        .background(Color.blue.cornerRadius(20))
            )
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    
}
func updateUI() {
   
    print("updateUI ran")
    
    self.num1 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)
           self.num2 = Int.random(in: 0 ... 10)
           self.number1 = "     \(self.num1)"
           self.number2 = "x   \(self.num2)"
           self.correctAnswer = num1 * num2
           self.answer = nil
}
```

Comment: Declare `answer` as `String` and convert the multiplication result to string